# Error in running default Web Application .Net Core 3

Tags: asp.net-core

I am choosing Empty template while creating a new asp.net core web application (.net core 3) as a option.
When I run project, I face with this error
[image]
System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.LoggingEventSource' threw an exception.'

Stack Trace:

```
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Host.<>c.<CreateDefaultBuilder>b__1_2(HostBuilderContext hostingContext, ILoggingBuilder logging)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_1.<ConfigureLogging>b__1(ILoggingBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging(IServiceCollection services, Action`1 configure)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingHostBuilderExtensions.<>c__DisplayClass4_0.<ConfigureLogging>b__0(HostBuilderContext context, IServiceCollection collection)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.CreateServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostBuilder.Build()
   at WebApplication2.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\WebApplication2\WebApplication2\Program.cs:line 16
```

Stack Trace in Inner Exception:

```
  at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.CompareString(ReadOnlySpan`1 string1, ReadOnlySpan`1 string2, CompareOptions options)
   at System.Globalization.CompareInfo.Compare(String string1, String string2, CompareOptions options)
   at System.Globalization.TextInfo.PopulateIsAsciiCasingSameAsInvariant()
   at System.Globalization.TextInfo.ChangeCaseCommon[TConversion](String source)
   at System.Globalization.TextInfo.ToUpper(String str)
   at System.String.ToUpperInvariant()
   at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource.GetGuid(Type eventSourceType)
   at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource..ctor(EventSourceSettings settings, String[] traits)
   at System.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventSource..ctor(EventSourceSettings settings)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventSource.LoggingEventSource..cctor()
```

What is this and how can I resolve it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please take a look at the Output tab and copy the full stack trace of the inner excption(s) and post them here.

Comment: I have added stack trace's text

Comment: Do you have the stack trace for the Inner Exeption? I see ArgumentException: External component has thrown an exception

Comment: @keuleJ
I have added stack trace in inner exception

Comment: I don't know a solution. Maybe you can look at this GitHub issue: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/19309

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved for me when I run the application on IIS instead of IIS Express.